Does adding two positive IEEE-754 floating point numbers ever result in a smaller number?
When dealing with floating point numbers, is there every a time when adding two non-negative, finite, non-NaN numbers will result in a result that is less than the greater of the two? $x + y < max(x, y)$. My gut feeling is no, but I know floating point numbers are complicated.

You'll have to be more specific about platform. Overflow is sometimes considered undefined behavior, and the result could indeed be a negative number.

Assuming this is IEEE-754, overflow is defined behaviour. It may be different behaviour depending on the mode, but it's never undefined.

@JimMischel I mean IEE-754. I wasn't thinking that there might be other standards. I'll update the question to be more clear.

No. Addition in IEEE-754 floating point a fairly simple process:

Compute the true mathematical sum of the two input operands.

Round the true sum to the nearest representable normal number, ignoring limits on the exponent for the moment.

If the exponent is larger than the largest allowed exponent, return infinity with the correct sign.

If the exponent is smaller than the smallest allowed exponent, round to the nearest subnormal representation.


The only part of this process that could go downwards to result in a smaller number is the rounding step. However, since both inputs are representable by definition, this rounding step can't possibly result in a number smaller than the input.

For completeness's sake, can you give an example of non representable numbers where it would get smaller? I'm just trying to understand. Is it because those numbers weren't rounded to representable ones yet?

@CaptainMan Try $1$ + $2^{100}$.

Note that on real CPUs, if either the FTZ or DAZ flags are enabled, the result can be smaller. Of course, your CPU is no longer IEEE-755 compliant with these flags enabled.
